# Map Flatten in JS?

Tags: javascript, ruby, node.js, dictionary

Looking through a json tree, I'm searching for all subscriptions belonging to a customer. In Ruby, I can say

```
customer.map(&:subscriptions).flatten
```

Is there an equivalent function for map flatten in JS?

Comment: please add some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods of javascript [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```
customers = [{ subscriptions: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}]}, { subscriptions: [{ id: 5 }]}]

customers
  .map(function(it) { return it.subscriptions })
  .reduce(function(memo, it) { return memo.concat(it) }, [])
```

Or using some ES6 syntax sugar:

```
customers = [{ subscriptions: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2}]}, { subscriptions: [{ id: 5 }]}]

customers
  .map(({ subscriptions }) => subscriptions)
  .reduce((memo, it) => (memo.concat(it)), [])
```

Also coming from Ruby, you may find [RubyJS](http://rubyjs.org/) interesting - which ports the ruby standard library to javascript. So you can write

```
R(customers, true).map(({ subscriptions }) => subscriptions).flatten().toNative()
```

Comment: There's also [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) now